# Chrome Extension: inject content script on fetched html

Tags: google-chrome-extension, scripting, service-worker, vite

I am building a Chrome extension that will improve a well-known website with some buttons to allow e.g. loading and saving preset, etc.

My stack right now is `crxjs`, `vite`, and `Svelte`.

When I navigate into the Settings page (F5 or Cmd+R or type in the URL), my content script runs correctly, and my buttons show up. However, when you switch from one Settings section to the other, even though the URL changes, my content script is not injected, probably because the website uses the service worker `fetch` to get the new HTML content.

My question is divided in two:

1. I used vite/rollup settings to emit separate files and used `chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts`. In this part, I'm stuck because I cannot emit the final file as iife or plain javascript (only modules seem to work). If someone can provide a solution for this, then #2 is not needed.
2. How can I inject my script after the fetch is executed (note that my extension runs its own service worker, I think I need to hack in the webpage own service worker, which might not be possible).

Well hope someone may have the answer
Thanks

Comment: For 2: use navigation.onnavigate ([example](/a/76597642/)).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

For #1, the error about failing to import was solved somehow. It was probably because I had to delete my dist folder and reload the extension. It started to work as is.

For #2, I found a solution using `MutationObserver`, which I found by chance, and I had never heard of it before.

The solution was to add a global content script for the entire website:

```
    content_scripts: [
        {
            js: ["global.js"],
            matches: ["https://thewebpage.com/**"],
        },
    ],
```

with this code:

```
const observer = new MutationObserver(async (mutationList) => {
    for (const mutation of mutationList) {
        // Monitor the removedNodes because it executes on the new page (addedNodes executes on the old page)
        if (mutation.removedNodes.length > 0) {
            // verify if it is the location you want
            if (window.location.href.match(new RegExp(href, "i"))) {
                // inject your code here
            }
        }
    }
});

// window.document.documentElement: <html> node
observer.observe(window.document.documentElement, { childList: true });
```

UPDATE: thanks @wOxxOm for the suggestion, I will try that `onnavigate`. It might be a better solution.